# What Canon mirrorless Camera would suit for product photography?

Tags: canon, product-photography, mirrorless

In our Company we have a special tool for making product photos. The tool consists of lightbox and turntable in it. It all connects to a PC where special software controls light intensity, turns the turntable and removes the background. The tool **works best only with Canon cameras**.

The main product that **we take pictures are spectacles and sunglasses**.

So having in mind both aspects what Canon camera model and what lens would suit our current situation?

P. S. We strongly believe, that **mirrorless cameras** are the best option for us as we make over 10k imager per month, so it's lifecycle should be longer.

Comment: I **do not want to advert any products**, but just to give you a hint here is the list of supported cameras and lenses https://orbitvu.com/camera-compatibility

Comment: Product photography is more about lighting, framing, composition, etc. than it is about the actual camera - you can do successful product photography with a point-n-shoot if you get the setting right.

Comment: Does your special software also trigger the camera? How?

Comment: Does the tool vendor suggest any models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirror-less does not suggest extended shutter life, as there is still a shutter in Canon mirrorless cameras. (There is not a mirror of course). The three current mirrorless models from Canon are the EOS R and RP, and the M. The R states a shutterlife of 200k actuations, while the RP has 100k actuations. The M has 100k. For comparison, the Canon 5D has 150k, the Canon 1D MkIV has 300k.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the RP can take pictures in silence mode (which does not trigger the shutter), but in silence mode you have to shoot in auto. If I remember correctly that's not the case with the EOS R : you can shoot in silence mode and in manual.

Comment: Re, "there is still a shutter..." Is there no option to turn it off? My non-Canon mirrorless camera offers me the option to either use the shutter, or to operate in "electronic shutter" mode.

Comment: At least in EOS RP, there is electronic first curtain and mechanical second curtain. Skipping the mechanical second curtain and using electronic second curtain results in a horrible rolling shutter effect because the readout speed is slower than the mechanical curtain, and the electronic first curtain has to match the slow readout speed. The setting to use electronic second curtain has been hidden extremely well: in practice, nobody uses it.

Comment: There are at least four different *current* EOS M bodies (M5, M6 Mark II, M50, M100), plus those that are discontinued (M, M3, M6, etc.).

Comment: @juhist For the OP's stated use case, rolling shutter has absolutely *zero* effect.

Comment: @MichaelC Agreed, but Canon's decision to hide the electronic second curtain extremely well (mainly because of the rolling shutter) has a lot of effect...

Comment: @juhist Exactly what effect would that be with regard to the OP's use case?

Comment: @MichaelC Well the effect is that it has been hidden in an "auto-exposure-mode", so you cannot control aperture or shutter speed if you are using the electronic second curtain shutter. I find that very limiting for product photography. Read more about it here: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/62306246 -- so you probably cannot control depth of field which is very important for macro photography, i.e. product photography of small things such as spectacles/sunglasses.

Comment: @juhist So one out of the current six Canon mirrorless bodies has this issue and you make a blanket statement above about all of them?

Comment: I don't recall making any statement about any other camera than EOS RP; I said "At least in EOS RP" because that's the camera I use.